# iOS SWIFT - JSON object nil after NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json, swift

hello I am trying to read JSON as an array from the server not the dictionary. If  I do this

```
let json: NSArray?
do {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray
    print("json is \(json)")
}
```

json object comes nil through this code and also I can't access the variable like this `json["code"]` I have tried this too

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSArray
```

But If I don't specify any type and let the variable as `AnyObject`

```
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
    print("json is \(json["code"]!)")                    
}
```

It works But 1st problem here is it prints Optional in the debugger but its least of my worries compared to that I can't do something like this

```
if json["code"] == 200 { 

}
```

If I do this it says

**Binary operator '==' cannot by applied to operands of type Anyobject? and Int**

what I want is to get the data in `NSArray`. I don't want the json variable to be set as `AnyObject`. Inshort I want this code to work

```
let json: NSArray?
do {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray
    print("json is \(json)")
}
```

if its possible. I don't know what I am doing wrong here

**json:**

```
 {"code":200,"msg":"login success"}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON?

Comment: if ```json``` is an Array, why do you try to do ```json["code"]```

Comment: @Joony I updated my question

Comment: @vadian is correct, your JSON is a dictionary not an array.

Comment: Before using an API, you should understand it. Can you explain why the .AllowFragment option? What makes you think that .MutableLeaves might make a difference?

Comment: @gnasher729 I would love if you can describe both these two practically. I checked the documentation but really don't able to understand the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If printing `json["code"]` works, then `json` is doubtless a dictionary.

`JSONObjectWithData` returns `AnyObject` that is
 "I-have-no-idea-what-it-is-but-it-is-some-kind-of-object-and-not-a-value" (thanks to gnasher729 for the more accurate paraphrase of `AnyObject`)

Since you know the object is `[String:AnyObject]` cast the type

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Then get the code – which is an `Int` – with

```
if json["code"] as! Int == 200 { 

}
```

or with optional binding if the key is optional

```
if let code = json["code"] as? Int { 
   if code == 200 {

   }
}
```

Comment: but why the json is a dictionary when I am putting an array in json_encode function on my server. how it changes to dictionary ?

Comment: The equivalent of an associative array in PHP `array(key  => value)` is a dictionary.

Comment: AnyObject is "I-have-no-idea-what-it-is-but-it-is-some-kind-of-object-and-not-a-value" Any is "I-have-no-idea-what-it-is".

Comment: Brillant, I updated my answer to use your better paraphrase